# Is it posiable to use exported variable in class in the same file its exported

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to use the exported variable in class in the same file its exported?

```js
exports.var = "something";

class c {
  constructor() {
    this.var = var;
  }
}
export.class = class;
```

Comment: Yes. `this.var = exports.var;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `this.var = exports.var;`
answer by [Patrick Hund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253156/patrick-hund)